# Efficiently extract frequency of signal from FFT

Tags: r, performance, audio, signal-processing, fft

I am using R and attempting to recover frequencies (really, just a number close to the actual frequency) from a large number of sound waves (1000s of audio files) by applying Fast Fourier transforms to each of them and identifying the frequency with the highest magnitude for each file.  I'd like to be able to recover these peak frequencies as quickly as possible.  The FFT method is one method that I've learned about recently and I think it should work for this task, but I am open to answers that do not rely on FFTs.  I have tried a few ways of applying the FFT and getting the frequency of highest magnitude, and I have seen significant performance gains since my first method, but I'd like to speed up the execution time much more if possible.

Here is sample data:

```
s.rate<-44100                        # sampling frequency
t <- 2                               # seconds, for my situation, I've got 1000s of 1 - 5 minute files to go through
ind <- seq(s.rate*t)/s.rate          # time indices for each step
                                     # let's add two sin waves together to make the sound wave
f1 <- 600                            # Hz: freq of sound wave 1
y <- 100*sin(2*pi*f1*ind)            # sine wave 1
f2 <- 1500                           # Hz: freq of sound wave 2
z <- 500*sin(2*pi*f2*ind+1)          # sine wave 2
s <- y+z                             # the sound wave: my data isn't this nice, but I think this is an OK example
```

The first method I tried was using the [fpeaks](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/seewave/docs/fpeaks) and [spec](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/seewave/docs/spec) functions from the [seewave](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/seewave/seewave.pdf) package, and it seems to work.  However, it is prohibitively slow.

```
library(seewave)
fpeaks(spec(s, f=s.rate), nmax=1, plot=F) * 1000  # *1000 in order to recover freq in Hz
[1] 1494
# pretty close, quite slow
```

After doing a bit more reading, I tried this next approach, wherein

```
spec(s, f=s.rate, plot=F)[which(spec(s, f=s.rate, plot=F)[,2]==max(spec(s, f=s.rate, plot=F)[,2])),1] * 1000 # again need to *1000 to get Hz
   x 
1494 
# pretty close, definitely faster
```

After a bit more looking around, I found this approach to work reasonably well.

```
which(Mod(fft(s)) == max(abs(Mod(fft(s))))) * s.rate / length(s)
[1] 1500  
# recovered the exact frequency, and quickly!
```

Here is some performance data:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  WHICH.MOD = which(Mod(fft(s))==max(abs(Mod(fft(s))))) * s.rate / length(s),
  SPEC.WHICH = spec(s,f=s.rate,plot=F)[which(spec(s,f=s.rate,plot=F)[,2] == max(spec(s,f=s.rate,plot=F)[,2])),1] * 1000,   # this is spec from the seewave package
  # to recover a number around 1500, you have to multiply by 1000
  FPEAKS.SPEC = fpeaks(spec(s,f=s.rate),nmax=1,plot=F)[,1] * 1000, # fpeaks is from the seewave package... again, need to multiply by 1000
  times=10)

Unit: milliseconds
        expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
   WHICH.MOD     10.78     10.81     11.07     11.43     12.33    10
  SPEC.WHICH     64.68     65.83     66.66     67.18     78.74    10
 FPEAKS.SPEC 100297.52 100648.50 101056.05 101737.56 102927.06    10
```

Good solutions will be the ones that recover a frequency close (± 10 Hz) to the real frequency the fastest.

## More Context

I've got many files (several GBs), each containing a tone that gets modulated several times a second, and sometimes the signal actually disappears altogether so that there is just silence.  I want to identify the frequency of the unmodulated tone. I know they should all be somewhere less than 6000 Hz, but I don't know more precisely than that.  If (big if) I understand correctly, I've got an OK approach here, it's just a matter of making it faster.  Just fyi, I have no previous experience in digital signal processing, so I appreciate any tips and pointers related to the mathematics / methods in addition to advice on how better to approach this programmatically.

Comment: The problem with using FFT is that it assumes that the input is periodic.  That is usually not the case for most frequencies present in a snapshot of a signal.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg My understanding is that I have a tone, which is a relatively constant frequency, say something like 800 ± 50 Hz , which gets modulate sometimes, but is the predominant frequency present in the signal. That would be considered periodic, right, and should be identifiable via this approach?  If not, why not; what I am misunderstanding?

Comment: What I mean by periodic, is that the FFT considers that the signal given is replayed back-to-back, to infinity in both directions.  That introduces edge effects for all but a few frequencies.  These edge effects may or may not color your results.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg Thanks for the tip; I'll have to visually check spectrograms for several files to see if the method seems to be working or having problems.  Any suggestions for handling the edge effects or for an alternate approach?

Comment: A smooth window applied at each end prior to the FT may help.  Wavelet transforms try to get around this problem, but you lose accuracy in the frequency domain (and gain accuracy in the time domain; note that the FT gives no time domain information).  I'm curious as to what you find with your real data with a windowed or non-windowed FT.  Other than "Windowed FFT", another search term that may help find relevant information is "Spectral Leakage."

Comment: @MatthewLundberg using a slightly modified version of `which(Mod(fft(s)) == max(abs(Mod(fft(s))))) * s.rate / length(s)` from above, I have checked ~ 20 files to see if I can recover the correct frequency (I determine the correct frequency visually by looking at the spectrogram), and the method has worked quite well each time.

Comment: You should consider answering your own question.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg OK, I will. I found alternate methods that are faster (but not always better, necessarily) than the methods that I have in the question, and the solutions in my answer below allow for window functions, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After coming to a better understanding of this task and some of the terminology involved, I came across some additional approaches, which I'll present here.  These additional approaches allow for window functions and a lot more, really, and the fastest approach in my question does not.  I also just sped things up a bit by assigning the result of some of the functions to an object and indexing the object instead of running the function again

```
#i.e.
(ms<-meanspec(s,f=s.rate,wl=1024,plot=F))[which.max(ms[,2]),1]*1000 
# instead of 
meanspec(s,f=s.rate,wl=1024,plot=F)[which.max(meanspec(s,f=s.rate,wl=1024,plot=F)[,2]),1]*1000
```

I have my favorite approach, but I welcome constructive warnings, feedback, and opinions.

```
microbenchmark(
  WHICH.MOD = which((mfft<-Mod(fft(s)))[1:(length(s)/2)] == max(abs(mfft[1:(length(s)/2)]))) * s.rate / length(s),
  MEANSPEC = (ms<-meanspec(s,f=s.rate,wl=1024,plot=F))[which.max(ms[,2]),1]*1000,
  DFREQ.HIST = (h<-hist(dfreq(s,f=s.rate,wl=1024,plot=F)[,2],200,plot=F))$mids[which.max(h$density)]*1000,
  DFREQ.DENS = (dens <- density(dfreq(s,f=s.rate,wl=1024,plot=F)[,2],na.rm=T))$x[which.max(dens$y)]*1000,
  FPEAKS.MSPEC = fpeaks(meanspec(s,f=s.rate,wl=1024,plot=F),nmax=1,plot=F)[,1]*1000 , 
  times=100)

Unit: milliseconds
         expr       min        lq    median        uq      max neval
    WHICH.MOD  8.119499  8.394254  8.513992  8.631377 10.81916   100
     MEANSPEC  7.748739  7.985650  8.069466  8.211654 10.03744   100
   DFREQ.HIST  9.720990 10.186257 10.299152 10.492016 12.07640   100
   DFREQ.DENS 10.086190 10.413116 10.555305 10.721014 12.48137   100
 FPEAKS.MSPEC 33.848135 35.441716 36.302971 37.089605 76.45978   100
```

`DFREQ.DENS` returns a frequency value farthest from the real value.  The other approaches return values close to the real value.

With one of my audio files (i.e. real data) the performance results are a bit different (see below).  One potentially relevant difference between the data being used above and the real data used for the performance data below is that above the data is just a vector of numerics and my real data is stored in a `Wave` object, an S4 object from the `tuneR` package.

```
library(Rmpfr) # to avoid an integer overflow problem in `WHICH.MOD`
microbenchmark(
  WHICH.MOD = which((mfft<-Mod(fft(d@left)))[1:(length(d@left)/2)] == max(abs(mfft[1:(length(d@left)/2)]))) * mpfr(s.rate,100) / length(d@left),
  MEANSPEC = (ms<-meanspec(d,f=s.rate,wl=1024,plot=F))[which.max(ms[,2]),1]*1000,
  DFREQ.HIST = (h<-hist(dfreq(d,f=s.rate,wl=1024,plot=F)[,2],200,plot=F))$mids[which.max(h$density)]*1000,
  DFREQ.DENS = (dens <- density(dfreq(d,f=s.rate,wl=1024,plot=F)[,2],na.rm=T))$x[which.max(dens$y)]*1000,
  FPEAKS.MSPEC = fpeaks(meanspec(d,f=s.rate,wl=1024,plot=F),nmax=1,plot=F)[,1]*1000 , 
  times=25) 

Unit: seconds
         expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
    WHICH.MOD 3.249395 3.320995 3.361160 3.421977 3.768885    25
     MEANSPEC 1.180119 1.234359 1.263213 1.286397 1.315912    25
   DFREQ.HIST 1.468117 1.519957 1.534353 1.563132 1.726012    25
   DFREQ.DENS 1.432193 1.489323 1.514968 1.553121 1.713296    25
 FPEAKS.MSPEC 1.207205 1.260006 1.277846 1.308961 1.390722    25
```

`WHICH.MOD` actually has to run twice to account for the left and right audio channels (i.e. my data is stereo), so it takes longer than the output indicates.  Note: I needed to use the `Rmpfr` library in order for the `WHICH.MOD` approach to work with my real data, as I was having problems with integer overflow.

Interestingly, `FPEAKS.MSPEC` performed really well with my data, and it seems to return a pretty accurate frequency (based on my visual inspection of a spectrogram).  `DFREQ.HIST` and `DFREQ.DENS` are quick, but the output frequency isn't as close to what I judge is the real value, and both are relatively ugly solutions.  My favorite solution so far `MEANSPEC` uses the `meanspec` and `which.max`.  I'll mark this as the answer since I haven't had any other answers, but feel free to provide an other answer.  I'll vote for it and maybe select it as the answer if it provides a better solution.